# Chain of dominos

Tags: prolog

I am learning prolog and solving some exercises on exercism.io. And I am stuck. I don't want to search for a solution on the internet, thus I will only a little help on the part of the exercise, since I don't understand where my mistake is, nor how to debug it.

The exercise is to create a legal [chain of dominos](https://exercism.org/tracks/prolog/exercises/dominoes). For that I wanted to write a simple checker.
`[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,1)]` as well as `[(1,1)]` or `[]` are legal. `[(1,2)]`, `[(1,2), (3,1)]` or `[(1,2),(2,3)]` are illegal. I can check it with my `is_chain`:

```
is_loop([]).
is_loop([(X,X)]).
is_loop([(L,_)|Xs]) :-
    last(Xs, (_, L)).

is_chain_no_loop([]).
is_chain_no_loop([(_, _)]).
is_chain_no_loop([(_,L), (L,Y)|Xs]) :-
    is_chain_no_loop([(L,Y)|Xs]).

is_chain(X) :-
    is_loop(X), is_chain_no_loop(X).
```

I split it into two parts. `is_loop` checks, whether the first and last element is compatible, `is_chain_no_loop` check the inner chain.

Here is where my confusion begins.

I can ask prolog, what kind of list are valid:
`is_chain(R).`

I get the following:

```
R = []
R = [(_1370,_1370)]
R = [(_1370,_1372), (_1372,_1370)]
R = [(_1370,_1372), (_1372,_1384), (_1384,_1370)]
R = [(_1370,_1372), (_1372,_1384), (_1384,_1396), (_1396,_1370)]
R = [(_1370,_1372), (_1372,_1384), (_1384,_1396), (_1396,_1408), (_1408,_1370)]
R = [(_1370,_1372), (_1372,_1384), (_1384,_1396), (_1396,_1408), (_1408,_1420), (_552,_502)]
```

I understand all but the last one. I am using SWISH, the online SWI-Prolog.
Why on earth is the last domino of `R` wrong? `_1420` doesn't match with `_552`, and `_502` doesn't match the first one's `_1370`.

On top of that, (since I assumed that `is_chain` is working correctly, but apparently it isn't) I started to implement `chain`, were given a `Pile` of dominos, I could get the proper `Chain` (if any).

```
chain([], Chain) :- is_chain(Chain).
chain([P, Pile], []) :- chain(Pile, [P]).
```

Now, this is not complete, but I don't understand things here either.
Given a `Chain`, it is a valid chain, if it `is_chain`. Simple.
If I don't have a `Chain`, then I just pick one `P` from the Pile and start with that.
Except that `chain([(1,1)], R)` is `false`. However `is_chain([(1,1)])` is `true`.

Considering everything, there seems to be something profound, that I don't understand about prolog or its execution (or its search). I am sorry that I can't break it down to a simpler example.

Edit:

After thinking more, I realized that `is_chain` can be implemented way simpler with a recursion that "eats" up the dominos:

```
is_chain([]).
is_chain([(X,X)]).
is_chain([(X,Y), (Y, Z)|Ls]) :-
    is_chain([(X,Z)|Ls]).
```

However, this leads to the same solutions...

Comment: I also fear that my question is not worthy of StackOverflow. This might be more suited for Reddit, or some IRC...
I still hope someone will nudge me into the right direction.

Comment: I suspect it is working and there is no error in your code. Try `is_chain(Dominos), Dominos = [First-_|_Rest]` and see that it keeps `First` in the start and end positions as the chain gets longer. I don't know what's happening; my suspicions are the start variable coming from `is_loop` and the end variable coming from `is_chain_no_loop([(_, _)])` making them *different variables* as long as they unify, whereas inside the chain it all comes from `is_chain([(X,Y), (Y, Z)|Ls]) :-` where `Y` is *the same variable* in two places. This is mostly guesswork and not a confident answer, though.

Comment: Learn how to debug Prolog, so that you can see what is happening, rather than be confused and stuck - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugoverview and its subpages.

Comment: Avoid "comma lists", they are confusing - https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/surprising-result-with-equals-dot-dot/4989 - can use e.g. `d(X, Y)` instead, to be a normal term.

Comment: Ugh; In my comment I meant `is_chain(Dominos), Dominos = [(First,_)|_Rest]` I had changed the code to use `X-Y` instead of `(X,Y)` for the dominos while playing with it, and forgot to change my example back.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler is right. If I try it with `is_chain(Dominos), Dominos = [(First,_)|_Rest]`, then the Dominos always show that `First` is both at the beginning and at the end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I don't understand prolog :D

@TessellatingHeckler pointed out, that I can test `is_chain` with `is_chain(Dominos), Dominos = [(First,_)|_Rest]`.

This confirms, that the code works just fine.

`chain` is just obviously wrong.